# Are questions about Chromebook apps off topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm baffled at the closure of [Distinguishing between Chrome OS apps and Android apps](https://superuser.com/questions/1669408/distinguishing-between-chrome-os-apps-and-android-apps).

How is this about anything other than "computer software and personal and home computer networking," two of the three items in the "on-topic guidelines?